# yq split kinds and unique name: -s is not keeping unique kind and metadata.name

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, yq

Below is my `testfile.yaml`:

```
---
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: amazing-application
---
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: amazing-deployment
---
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: amazing-deployment
---
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: tea-service
```

My goal is to split this into 4 files where the filename is `.metadata.name` and the dir that file goes into is `.kind`.

I have achieved what I want with this:

```
for kind in $(yq e '.kind' testfile.yaml | awk '!/^(---)/' | uniq); 
do 
  mkdir "$kind"
  cd "$kind"
  yq 'select(.kind == "'$kind'")' ../testfile.yaml | yq -s '.metadata.name' 
  cd ..;
done
```

What I want to know is how to get a unique together mapping, or somehow using multple criteria to split the testfile rather than through the loop.

Is there a way to use `yq` and `-s` or `select` to select where kind and metadata.name are unique together in that individual document (document as in separated by '---')?

Because if you do `yq -s '.kind' testfile.yaml` it will yield three yaml files, not four. Same for `yq -s '.metadata.name' testfile.yaml`; we get three files as not all `name` are unique - one gets lost.

Comment: `kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: amazing-application` should be the content of first file?

Comment: How about just `yq -s '"file_" + $index'` it creates 4 files `file_0`..`file_3`

Comment: Please post the _exact_ contents of each of the files

Comment: Don't post images or links, just plain text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways you can do this direct in yq.

First of, you can use string concatenation with another property to comeup with a unique filename:

```
yq -s '(.kind | downcase) + "_" + .metadata.name' testfile.yaml
```

That will create files like:

```
deployment_amazing-deployment.yml
pod_amazing-application.yml
service_amazing-deployment.yml
service_tea-service.yml
```

Or you can use the built in $index to make the filenames unique:

```
yq -s '.metadata.name + "_" + $index'
```

Which will create:

```
amazing-application_0.yml
amazing-deployment_1.yml
amazing-deployment_2.yml
tea-service_3.yml
```

Disclaimer: I wrote yq

Comment: See https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/usage/split-into-multiple-files for more info and examples

Answer (score 1):

According to your shell-scripted workaround, you want to store each document into its own file named after `.metadata.name` in a subdirectory named after `.kind`. However, yq's [split option](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/usage/split-into-multiple-files#split-single-document-into-files) `-s` cannot create subdirectories, and would fail when provided with naming schemes such as `-s '.kind + "/" + .metadata.name'`.

Alternatives:

- You can try submitting a [feature request](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/issues). The author is quite open for adaptations towards new use-cases. In fact, the `-s` option by itself also came to life [this way](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/issues/966).
- You could (temporarily) replace the `/` character from above for something else (valid but not contained in the names otherwise), and then with a shell script just iterate over the files moving and renaming them into the right places (altogether resulting in just one call to `yq`). Example using `_` instead:

  ```bash
  yq -s '.kind + "_" + .metadata.name' . testfile.yaml && for f in *_*
  do mkdir -p "${f%%_*}" && mv "$f" "${f%%_*}/${f#*_}"; done
  ```
- Depending on your overall goal with the files/documents, you could consider  working with copies of the original file, each reduced to just those documents "belonging together", i.e. replacing the subdirectories with files, and keeping a grouped set of documents within those files. Example using the `eval-all` (or `ea`) [command](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/commands/evaluate-all) in combination with `[.]` to generate an array of documents, then `group_by` on `.kind` to collect into sub-arrays those that share the criteria given, and finally `.[] | split_doc` to turn those groups into documents again, in order to be captured by `-s`.

  ```bash
  yq ea -s '.[0].kind' '[.] | group_by(.kind) | .[] | split_doc' testfile.yaml
  ```

  Given your example, here you'd intentionally get only three files, but with one containing two documents, and two containing one. Note that technically the outputs are still just arrays of (former) documents, not "real" multi-document files, They'd need another `.[] | split_doc` applied to each one of them in order to properly re-convert them as such (not covered here).

Comment: if I would like to get 3 valid yaml files how the next command should be executed?

Comment: @mat656 I assume you are referring to the last of the three alternatives. All three files generated are valid yaml files but with an additional layer of structure (an array) inside. To strip that layer turning them back into proper multi-document files (with `---` in between documents, observable if the array had more than one item), just run `yq '.[] | split_doc'` on those files (individually). Don't forget to use the `-i` flag if you want to update the files in-place. Is this what you were asking?